# Should I prioritize CP or moves?

Tags: pokemon-go

I had a Pidgey, I evolved it and it became a Pidgeotto with 110 CP. Its moves are Wing Attack(12) and Twister(15) (I'm not sure what those numbers mean, but I suppose it's their damage).

Today I saw another Pidgeotto and caught it. It has 48 CP and its moves are Wing Attack(12) and Aerial Ace(25). How can I decide which of them I should go with?

The first Pidgeotto has way more CP but one of my friends told me that moves have a big impact and the second Pidgeotto has Aerial Ace(25).

Will the second Pidgeotto ever catch up to the first's CP, and can I ever teach the first Pidgeotto different moves?

Answer (score 15):

Two things to have in mind :

- You can power-up your pokemon to increase CP. In this case, moves will be more important. The 48 CP Pidgeotto will just need to power-up a little more.
- With evolution, pokémon can (will) change their moves. So, if you want to evolve your Pidgeotto, their current moves don't matter. Evolve the 110 CP Pidgeotto; if you don't like its moves or think you can get better, evolve the second one.

Remember : Look for moves if the pokemon can't evolve any more, then CP. And the more CP, the better!

Comment: do moves change if the type doesn't change? all my Pidgey > Pidgeotto > Pidgeot have stayed the same as far as I remember, same for Weedle > Kakuna, but Kakuna > Beedrill has meant new moves

Comment: @RickyTillson yes, even if there is no type change. The moves will most likely change, but they do sometimes stay the same. Evolution is not a guarantee of a changed moveset, except in the cases of Eevee evolutions.

Answer (score 5):

CP is more important until a pokemon reaches it's final form.  Every time it evolves, its attacks essentially get shuffled and it may have brand new ones.  As far as I can tell so far there is no way to predict what attacks you'll get after evolution, so until it's final form, just evolve the higher CP one.  Once you get duplicates in the final form, this is when attack types matter, as they are permanent at this point since there is no more evolution.  At that time, choose the one that has the attacks you want and train that one.

Answer (score 5):

### Prioritise Appraisal (Stars), then Combat Power (CP)

With the new Appraisal system it's easier to determine which Pokemon will be best. 3-Star Pokemon have higher base stats, and therefore a higher (maximum) CP.

(Note 3 star Pokemon with pink colour indicates a Pokemon with perfect stats, and are called '4-star'):

[image: 3 Star] vs [image: 4 Star - 100%]

You can search your Pokemon using the terms `0*`, `1*`, `2*`, `3*` or `4*` to filter Pokemon by their appraisal.

Note that lower-star Pokemon with high CP are still useful, especially at lower trainer levels, so keep a few that are high CP too.

### Don't worry too much about moves.

A Pokemon's moves can now be changed with the 'Fast TM' and 'Charged TM' consumable items, which can be earned through various means (Raids, Research Tasks, Special Research, Friend Gifts etc).

Comment: Are you sure that a Friend gift can give TMs?

Comment: @Styx I was fairly certain I've gotten one or two, but now I'm not sure.

Comment: https://www.imore.com/pokemon-go-technical-machines, this source says they are only gotten through raids and special research.

Comment: "Don't worry too much about moves," if you have plenty of TMs.  For some trainers, TMs are quite scarce.